# pyspark filter condition on multiple columns by .all() or any()

Tags: pyspark

I'd like to filter a df based on multiple columns where all of the columns should meet the condition. Below is the python version:

```
df[(df["a list of column names"] <= a value).all(axis=1)]
```

Is there any straightforward function to do this in pyspark?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first calculate the condition and filter the any or all column

```
data = [
    [1.0,1.0,1.0],
    [2.0,2.0,1.0],
]
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)

df.withColumn('all', f.aggregate(f.array(*df.columns), f.lit(True), lambda acc, x: acc & (x <= 1))) \
  .withColumn('any', f.aggregate(f.array(*df.columns), f.lit(False), lambda acc, x: acc | (x <= 1))) \
  .show()

+----+----+----+-----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|  all| any|
+----+----+----+-----+----+
| 1.0| 1.0| 1.0| true|true|
| 2.0| 2.0| 1.0|false|true|
+----+----+----+-----+----+
```

Answer (score 2):

##### .any

```
# You can omit "== True"
df.filter(F.greatest(*[F.col(c) <= 100 for c in df.columns]) == True)
```

##### .all

```
# You can omit "== True"
df.filter(F.least(*[F.col(c) <= 100 for c in df.columns]) == True)
```

`greatest` will take the max value in a list and for boolean it will take `True` if there is any `True`, so filter by greatest == True is equivalent to `any`.

While, `least` will take the min value and for boolean it will take `False` if there is any `False`. If `least` is `True`, that means all values are `True`, therefore filter by least == True is equivalent to `all`.